# Erro "405 Method Not Allowed" no postman - REST API spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

Estou tentando executar o metodo delete no postman mas da esse erro "405 Method Not Allowed
", consigo executar os outros metodos put, post e get de boa.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cidade")
public class CidadeREST {
    @Autowired
    private RepositorioCidade repositorioCidade;

    @GetMapping
    public Page<Cidade> listar(Pageable page){
        return repositorioCidade.findAll(page);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public void salvar(@RequestBody Cidade cidade){
        repositorioCidade.save(cidade);
    }

    @PutMapping
    public void alterar(@RequestBody Cidade cidade){
        if(cidade.getIdCidade() > 0)
        repositorioCidade.save(cidade);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{idCidade}")        
    public void excluir(@PathVariable Long idCidade){
        repositorioCidade.deleteById(idCidade);
    }
}
```

[image: erro]

Comment: Não será porque o método DELETE é o único que está esperando o parâmetro `idCidade`? No caso você fez a requisição somente até a raiz `/cidade`, que está no escopo de todos os métodos, exceto do `DeleteMapping`.

Answer (score -1):

Você não especificou o ID ao fazer a requisição.
Portanto ele está fazendo a requisição para outra rota que realmente não está mapeada.

Sua rota na API: DELETE /cidade/{id}

A rota que você está chamando: DELETE /cidade

Answer (score -2):

Você não passou o id para fazer o request, então ele está chamando uma rota que não existe (/cidade) quando a rota certa seria

http://localhost:8080/cidade/{id da cidade}}

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Quando fizer o request, use o caminho completo:
Veja no exemplo:

http://localhost:8080/cidade/1

Perceba que o valo /1 após cidade é o numero do Id que vc quer deletar.
Este numero deve  existir no banco de dados, para isso execute a query.

```
SELECT * FROM CIDADE;
```

Eu julguei que sua tabela no banco de dados se chama CIDADE, caso não seja coloque o nome correto no local.

Assim que tiver o resultado, veja qual id pode usar para o delete.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

O erro que está acontecendo é por causa que foi mapeado a variavel {idCidade} na URI da API, mas não foi passado nenhum outro valor.

Uma dica usar o mesmo padrão do método DELETE paara o método updade e por fim para o método get precisa mapear as informações de paginação para repassar para camada de repository.

Um padrão bem comum é setar valores default (padrão) para página e tamanho da página ao retornar os valores solicitados.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).